# AWS An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-iam, aws-cli, wsl-2

Due to license policy, our organization cannot use Docker Desktop for Windows. We use Docker console inside Ubuntu 22.04 WSL2. Therefore, before working with AWS ECR, I worked inside Ubuntu 22.04 . With same credentials `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` , region `eu-central-1`:

On Windows 10, cmd

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\dnvy>aws s3 ls
2023-11-10 00:32:35 aws-landing-zone-local-cf-logs-053297099947-eu-central-1
2023-11-10 00:32:19 aws-landing-zone-local-cf-logs-053297099947-eu-west-1
2023-11-10 00:32:35 aws-landing-zone-local-elb-logs-053297098447-eu-central-1
2023-11-10 00:32:19 aws-landing-zone-local-elb-logs-053297098447-eu-west-1
2023-11-10 00:32:02 aws-landing-zone-local-s3-access-logs-099997098447-eu-central-1
2023-11-10 00:31:55 aws-landing-zone-local-s3-access-logs-053297098447-eu-west-1
2023-11-10 00:32:35 aws-landing-zone-local-waf-logs-053297099947-eu-central-1
2023-11-10 00:32:19 aws-landing-zone-local-waf-logs-053297098997-eu-west-1
2023-12-11 09:30:56 xxaxx-app-bucket
2023-12-11 08:06:33 xxxxx-xxth
2023-12-11 22:36:51 serverless-xxxxxx-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-xxsjpddxx3gi
2023-12-11 20:55:51 serverless-next-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-ljbtxxagtmsk
2023-12-13 00:43:50 www.yyas33-xxv.xxxllixx44.net

C:\Users\dnvy>
```

It was success.

On Ubuntu 22.04 WSL 2 (inside Windows 10) (I revised secret for security, it is not real credentials)

```
root@WS0419:~# aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************SI1X]: XXIAQY2GBF3HQNXXSI1X
AWS Secret Access Key [****************icEh]: 9Lx+HhgSxDucxZ0TvAgvr5kG2uqebx3WBYggicEh
Default region name [eu-central-1]: eu-central-1
Default output format [json]: json
root@WS0419:~# aws s3 ls

An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
root@WS0419:~# aws

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

aws: error: the following arguments are required: command

root@WS0419:~#
```

It is fail.

How to make AWS CLI login success inside Ubuntu 22.04 WSL2?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

In file `credentials`, delete `aws_session_token` (key and value). then

```
aws configure
```

re-enter credentials.